# Socket.IO not using fallback methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a node server that's running a socket.io server and a client to work with it. Simple story, I need to be able to transfer messages between the two. This is working as intended in browsers that support web sockets but when a fallback method needs to be used its not working.
I should mention that pages are served from an apache server and the node server is only used for a specific page. The code that I am using is below, I've tinkered on this for a while and can't figure out how to fix it.

Also worth mentioning that when the page is opened in IE9(websockets not supported),
logging connection.io.engine.transport.name would give "websocket".

Client:

```
            connection = io(window.location.protocol + '//localhost:8888', {
                'reconnect': false,
                'max reconnection attempts': 0,
                'transports': 
                            [
                             'websocket',
                             'flashsocket',
                             'htmlfile',
                             'xhr-polling',
                             'jsonp-polling'
                            ]
            });

            connection.on('connect',function () {
                    console.log("Socket is open");
                    $('#dc-status').hide();
                    connection.emit('message',JSON.stringify(info));

                    connection.on('message',function (e) {
                        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA RECIEVED
                    });
            });
```

Server:
    var ioserver = require('socket.io');

```
var io = ioserver.listen(8888);

var http = require("http");


console.log("server started...");


io.set('transports',[
                    'websocket',
                    'flashsocket',
                    'htmlfile',
                    'xhr-polling',
                    'jsonp-polling'
                    ]);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(ws) {

    var req;
    var order;
    var courier;
    var after;
    var session;
    var options = {};
    console.log("New client connected");


    // console.log("Transport: " + io.transports[ws.id].name);

    ws.on('message', function(data) {

        //WORK WITH THE DATA RECEIVED
        //NOT RELEVANT TO EXAMPLE
        console.log('received: %s', data);

        parsedData = JSON.parse(data);


    });

   ws.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("Connection closed");
    });

});
```

Comment: Socket.io > 1.0 no longer uses fallbacks and instead uses upgrade methods. `Socket.IO never assumes that WebSocket will just work, because in practice there’s a good chance that it won’t. Instead, it establishes a connection with XHR or JSONP right away, and then attempts to upgrade the connection to WebSocket. `.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would this mean that I would need to refactor the server code then? Because when I open the page in IE9 lets say, I don't even get the "server started..." log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after much struggle with this I have found a solution for making sockets work in old browsers.

As of version 1.0 Socket.io uses Engine.io instead of fallback methods, which takes care of transports.
To get a working solution I skipped using the Socket.io layer and used just Engine.io instead.
In the client you have something like

```
var connection = eio.Socket('host-address');
```

and then you just bind the regular events(e.g message, close).

And in the server part instead of require('Socket.IO'), you call require('Engine.IO'), example:

```
var engineio = require('engine.io');
var wss = engineio.listen(10101);
```

The binding is the same.